# How do I install Compiz in Xubuntu?

Tags: compiz, xubuntu

How can i properly set up Compiz in Xubuntu?

Comment: Are you sure you want to install compiz? For some simple compositing effects like transparency it is worthwile to just activate XFWMs own compositor. See, for instance: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=138373

Answer (score 10):

Compiz is not installed on Xubuntu for reasons of lightness but it can be installed:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compiz-plugins-main compiz-plugins-extra
```

Change to compiz:

```
compiz --replace
```

Install Compiz Config Settings Manager too:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

You can find **compizconfig-settings-manager** in **System -> Preferences**

Answer (score 1):

```
$sudo apt-get install compiz gnome-themes compizconfig-settings-manager
$compiz --replace ccp &
```

Be sure to go to Settings Manager->Sessions and Startup to add the line:

```
compiz --replace ccp
```

to ensure that compiz loads each time you start your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here

http://xubuntublog.wordpress.com/2007/12/09/xubuntu-compiz-pretty-pretty-xubuntu/

Post is a bit old, but i guess it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this for the latest 11.04 release. Seems pretty complete though I have yet to try it

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1754637