# Xubuntu 17.10: compiz cannot start

Tags: xubuntu, compiz, xfce

I setup Compiz for my Xubuntu 17.10 based on the answer here: [How do I install Compiz in Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8270/how-do-i-install-compiz-in-xubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compiz-plugins-main compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

And attempted to start Compiz like this:

```
perret@perret-ThinkPad-E460:~/Desktop/Test$ compiz --replace
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : ini
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : default
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: decor
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
```

However even if the window decoration is enabled it seems that I end up with no windows decorations...

I checked the answers here: [Compiz in XFCE4- Ubuntu-17.04: Setup progress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/957778/compiz-in-xfce4-ubuntu-17-04-setup-progress)

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
compiz --replace
```

Or, reset:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

Then start it. It will work.

Comment: If you check my extract, you can I'm doing "compiz --replace" and that there is an error about the pixmap decoration.

Comment: Does not work, both of them, the first command "compiz --replace"  gives the log submitted in my post

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8270/how-do-i-install-compiz-in-xubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1